# Do I need the v-baffles sitting on top of pool heater's heat exchanger?

Tags: heating, pool

I just finished cleaning the soot out of my pool heater. Actually the biggest problem was all of the rust and scale left behind by the v baffle bars that sit on top of the heat exchanger. I was wondering if there is any safety reason I shouldn't run my heater without them or if it's just an efficiency / effectiveness thing.